# Calling a method after user shares with Facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used addThis and share kit in the past, but got tired of having issues.  I finally went through the Facebook sdk stuff and got it working.  I’m using this to post to a user’s wall...

```
-(IBAction)fbPost:(id)sender
{
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes", 
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"publish_stream",
                            nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];

}


SBJSON *jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];

NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Name", @"name",
                            @"Test Caption", @"caption",
                            @"This sure is fun", @"description",
                            @"http://www.test.com/", @"href", nil];
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@“xxxxxxxxxx",@"app_id",
                               @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                               actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               @"Here is the message",@"message",
                               nil];

AppDelegate *aDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[aDelegate.facebook dialog:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

My question is... is there s way for me to tell that the user posted to their wall?  Say for example I’d like to post a message “Thank you for sharing on Facebook” or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an ios developer, but from the [FBDialogDelegate documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/FBDialogDelegate/) it looks like you can know when the user has posted with the `dialogDidComplete` method:

> This method is invoked after the dialog succeeds and is about to be
>   hidden. You can use this method to handle the success path of the
>   dialog flow.

You might also want to check the other methods to know if the user canceled or there was an error.

Looks like you are passing `self` for the dialog, just implement those methods there.

Comment: Perfect that’s what I wanted.